# Error 1248 in MySQL: "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1 
FROM 
  (
   SELECT CONCAT(retailerId,'_recharge') FROM retailerinformation
   WHERE Channel='videocon' AND retailerId='kioskpb20130909045617'
  )
```

but every time on running I get this error:

```
Error Code : 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias
```

Comment: What confuses me is that you have a string expression for `retailerId`, but look it up in a table anyway. Why do you do that?

Comment: You can save a lot of time by just saying "SELECT 'kioskpb20130909045617_recharge';" since you're not really getting much new information from the database (other than that a record exists).

Answer (score 3):

Your error is very clear. Create an alias:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  col1 
FROM 
  (select concat(retailerId,'_recharge') from retailerinformation where Channel='videocon' and retailerId='kioskpb20130909045617') AS tmp_table
```

*hint:* if you'll try to *understand* errors, not just read them - this will be success story.

Answer (score 0):

Try this version:

```
select DISTINCT col1 from 
 (select concat(retailerId,'_recharge') from retailerinformation
   where Channel='videocon' and retailerId='kioskpb20130909045617') as retailerino
```

Note the alias on your subquery.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT col1
FROM (
   SELECT concat(retailerId,'_recharge') 
   FROM retailerinformation where Channel='videocon' and retailerId='kioskpb20130909045617'
   ) AS alias
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding the alias on the subquery, columns called on the outer query should exist in the sub query. In this case, col1 should exist in the sub query. With that said, this should work

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1 
FROM 
  (
   SELECT CONCAT(retailerId,'_recharge') col1 FROM retailerinformation
   WHERE Channel='videocon' AND retailerId='kioskpb20130909045617'
  ) sub
```